# how to use a global variable witch is defined in other dll?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, cmake, global-variables, lnk2001

I have `globalInfo.dll` for

Source file:

```
#include "util/timer.h"
#include "util/winDll.h"
namespace GLOBAL
{
    DLL_EXPORT timer::timestamp currentTime;
    DLL_EXPORT timer globalTimer;
    static void timerAction (uint64_t nowTime, void* nptr)
    {
        currentTime.time = nowTime;
    }
    DLL_EXPORT void init()
    {
        currentTime.time = timer::getNowTimestamp();
        globalTimer.start();
        globalTimer.addTimer(nullptr, timerAction, 1000000);
    }
    DLL_EXPORT void close()
    {
        globalTimer.stop();
    }
}
```

Header file:

```
#pragma once
#include "util/timer.h"
#include "util/winDll.h"
namespace GLOBAL
{
    DLL_IMPORT extern timer::timestamp currentTime;
    DLL_IMPORT extern timer globalTimer;
    constexpr static auto version = "0.1.0";
    DLL_EXPORT void init();
    DLL_EXPORT void close();
}
```

I use `currentTime` in other `dll` with:

```
now.time = GLOBAL::currentTime.time;
```

This is a CMake project, I use `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` to link `globalInfo`.
On Linux platform all is OK, but on Windows Visual Studio 2019 I got an LNK2001 error:

```
**struct timer::timestamp GLOBAL::currentTime" (?currentTime@GLOBAL@@3Utimestamp@timer@@A)**
```

My `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
aux_source_directory(database databaseDir)
add_library(database SHARED ${databaseDir})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(database  util globalInfo thread memory meta ${LZ4} ${GLOG} ${GFLAGS})
target_include_directories(database PUBLIC ${BASE_INCLUDE_PATH} ${GLOG_INCLUDE_PATH} ${GLFAG_INCLUDE_PATH})
```

Comment: Can you show us how are you definining your `DLL_IMPORT` and `DLL_EXPORT` macros?

Comment: #pragma once
#ifndef OS_WIN
#define DLL_EXPORT
#define DLL_IMPORT
#endif 
#ifdef OS_WIN
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#define DLL_IMPORT __declspec(dllimport )
#endif

Comment: You need DLL_EXPORT in the header too, why did you put DLL_IMPORT there?